# .NET 7 API accepting revoked token by Keycloak

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, keycloak

.NET 7 API accepting revoked token  by Keycloak

Scenario:
.NET 7 API is accepting the token even that token have been revoked by Keycloak.

Simple sample of configuration auth:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters();
    options.Authority = "authorityUrl";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.Audience = "audience";
});
```

Controller anoted with `[Authorize]` attribute.

Steps:

1. Attempt request to the API without add a valid bearer
   RESULT: 401 unauthorized;
2. Attempt request to the API with a invalid bearer
   RESULT: 401 unauthorized;
3. Attempt request to the API with a valid bearer
   RESULT: 200 ok;
4. Revoke token with keycloak endpoint
   RESULT: Token revoked successfully;

**5. Attempt request to the API with the revoked bearer
RESULT: 200 ok;**

.net authentication is not validating the token validity.
I think I can create a token handler to call keycloak instrospect endpoint to get the token validity but i'm not sure that it's a good idea because of performance issues.

Is there a way to check the token validity every request?

NOTE: I don't want to validate the token expiration date. I want to check if the token is active or not.